# Extra blue space below an img

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-title Traffic">کاردستی</div>
        <div class="item-content">
            <a href=""><img src="images/kardasti.png" width="100%" ></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the result is:

[image]

Why is this blue area showing below the image?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post your CSS, too. But try removing the `<a>` tag surrounding the image and see if it's still there

Comment: I had a similar whitespace issue once and I did it by putting `display: block` on the `img` tag

Answer (score 1):

It's because images are intrinsically set to `display: inline`, so they render similarly to text. Text has line-height that extends above and below the letters, so if there is a background-color, it fills that line-height.

Set your image to `display: block` in order to nullify the line-height.